# Join most recent Date AND other fields that belong to that date from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to JOIN a different table that has DATE values in it, and I only want the most recent Date to be added and te most recent Value that corresponds with that Date.

I have a table in which certain RENTALOBJECTS in the RENTALOBJECTTABLE have a N:1 relationship with the OBJECTTABLE

```
RENTALOBJECTTABLE:
RENTALOBJECTID, OBJECTID
1,              1
2,              1
3,              2
4,              3
5,              4
6,              4


OBJECTTABLE:
OBJECTID
1
2
3
4
```

Every OBJECTID can (and usually has, more than 1) VALUE

```
VALUETABLE:
OBJECTID,   VALUE,  VALIDFROM,  VALIDTO,    CODE
1,          2000,   1-1-1950,   31-12-1980, A
1,          3000,   1-1-1981,   31-12-2010, A
1,          4000,   1-1-2013,   NULL,       A
2,          1000,   1-1-1970,   NULL,       A
3,          2000,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       A
4,          2000,   1-1-2000,   31-12-2009, A
4,          3100,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       B
4,          3000,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       A
```

And combined I want for every RentalObject the most recent VALUE to be shown. End result expected:

```
RENTALOBJECTTABLE_WITHVALUE:
RENTALOBJECTID, OBJECTID,   VALUE,  VALIDFROM,  VALIDTO,    CODE
1,              1,          4000,   1-1-2013,   NULL,       A
2,              1,          4000,   1-1-2013,   NULL,       A
3,              2,          1000,   1-1-1970,   NULL,       A
4,              3,          2000,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       A
5,              4,          3000,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       A
6,              4,          3000,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       A
```

I so far managed to get the Most Recent Date joined to the table with the code below. However, as soon as I want to INCLUDE VALUETABLE.VALUE then the rowcount goes from 5000 (what the original dataset has) to 48000.

```
SELECT
RENTALOBJECTTABLE.RENTALOBJECTID
FROM RENTALOBJECTTABLE
LEFT JOIN OBJECTTABLE
    ON OBJECTTABLE.OBJECTID = RENTALOBJECTTABLE.OBJECTID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        OBJECTID,
        CODE,
        VALUE, --without this one it gives the same rows as the original table
        MAX(VALIDFROM) VALIDFROM
    FROM VALUETABLE
    LEFT JOIN PMETYPE 
        ON VALUETABLE.CODE = PMETYPE.RECID
        AND PMETYPE.REGISTERTYPENO = 6
        WHERE PMETYPE.[NAME] = 'WOZ'
    GROUP BY OBJECTID, CODE, VALUE
    ) VALUETABLE ON OBJECTTABLE.OBJECTID = VALUETABLE.OBJECTID
```

When I include MAX(VALUE) next to the MAX(Date) it obviously has the original 5000 dataset rows again, but now it only selects the most recent date + highest value, which is not always correct.

Anyone any clue about how to solve this issue? 
I think I miss something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you close

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        o.OBJECTID,
        v.VALUE,
        v.VALIDFROM,
        v.VALIDTO,
        v.CODE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.OBJECTID ORDER BY v.VALIDFROM DESC ) rn
    FROM dbo.OBJECTTABLE o 
    INNER JOIN dbo.VALUETABLE v ON v.OBJECTID = o.OBJECTID
)
SELECT ro.RENTALOBJECTID,
       ro.OBJECTID,
       cte.OBJECTID,
       cte.VALUE,
       cte.VALIDFROM,
       cte.VALIDTO,
       cte.CODE
FROM dbo.RENTALOBJECTTABLE ro 
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.OBJECTID = ro.OBJECTID
    AND rn=1;
```

However, this might pull out the 3100 value for object 4 - there is nothing to separate the two values with the same validfrom. If you have (or can add) an identity column to the value table, you can use this in the order by on the partitioning to select the row you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Sample Data**

```
select * into #RENTALOBJECTTABLE from (
SELECT 1 AS RENTALOBJECTID, 1 OBJECTID
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2
UNION ALL SELECT 4,3
UNION ALL SELECT 5,4
UNION ALL SELECT 6,4) A


SELECT * INTO #OBJECTTABLE FROM(
SELECT 
1 OBJECTID
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4)AS B



SELECT * INTO #VALUETABLE FROM (
SELECT   1OBJECTID,2000 VALUE,'1-1-1950'VALIDFROM,'31-12-1980' VALIDTO, 'A' CODE
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3000,'1-1-1981','31-12-2010', 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,4000,'1-1-2013',NULL,       'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1000,'1-1-1970',NULL,       'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2000,'1-1-2010',NULL,       'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,2000,'1-1-2000','31-12-2009', 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,3100,'1-1-2010',NULL,       'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,3000,'1-1-2010',NULL,       'A'
) AS C
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY OBJECTID ORDER BY OBJECTID DESC)RN FROM #VALUETABLE
)
SELECT RO.RENTALOBJECTID,RO.OBJECTID,C.VALUE,C.VALIDFROM,C.VALIDTO,C.CODE
FROM CTE C 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT OBJECTID,MAX(RN)RN FROM CTE C1 WHERE C.OBJECTID=C1.OBJECTID GROUP BY OBJECTID )AS B
INNER JOIN #RENTALOBJECTTABLE RO ON RO.OBJECTID=C.OBJECTID
WHERE  C.OBJECTID=B.OBJECTID AND C.RN=B.RN
```

**OutPut Data:**

```
RENTALOBJECTID, OBJECTID,   VALUE,  VALIDFROM,  VALIDTO,    CODE
1,              1,          4000,   1-1-2013,   NULL,       A
2,              1,          4000,   1-1-2013,   NULL,       A
3,              2,          1000,   1-1-1970,   NULL,       A
4,              3,          2000,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       A
5,              4,          3000,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       A
6,              4,          3000,   1-1-2010,   NULL,       A
```